# .htaccess redirect all urls not beginning with /foo/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all URLS of my website which don't begin with /foo/.

Example:

```
/page.html -> /foo/page.html 
/foo1/page.html -> /foo/foo1/page.html
```

Etc.

Actually I have that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule (.*) www.example.com/foo/$1 [QSA,L,R=301,NC]
```

But I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `www.example.com` from your rule

`RewriteRule (.*) /foo/$1 [QSA,L,R=301,NC]`